# componentsSeparatedByString - get component that is the string being split on

Tags: string, swift

I'm using `componentsSeparatedByString` on String to split a long String into a String array using the comma (,) as the string to split on. The problem is, one component is the comma character. For example, the string is "a,b,c,,,1,2,3". After calling `componentsSeparatedByString` the array is ["a", "b", "c", "", "", "1", "2", "3"] but I need it to be ["a", "b", "c", ",", "1", "2", "3"]. Luckily I can modify the string but I really don't want to change all of the commas to a different character. Is there a way I can 'escape' the comma I need as a component such that `componentsSeparatedByString` won't split on that middle one?

I tried replacing it with `\u{002C}`, but it was smarter than that. Still interprets that as a comma so it splits on it.

Comment: `"a,b,c,,,1,2,3"` _should_ parse to `["a", "b", "c", "", "", "", "1", "2", "3"]`. That just makes sense. Perhaps you should use a proper CSV format and a proper CSV parser library? Which means you would quote any item that contains the delimiter character. `a,b,c,",",1,2,3`. Like this library perhaps: https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV

Comment: You will have a problem: how will act your algorithm with this: `"a,,,,b"`? How can it knows if the result is: `["a", ",", "", "b"]` or `["a", "", ",", "b"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead of `componentsSeparatedByString` you do it using the `split` method from the standard library, you can use a stateful closure to do it in a fairly hacky way by remembering if the last element was a comma and then not splitting on two in a row:

```
let s = "a,b,c,,,1,2,3"

var lastWasComma = false
let array = split(s.characters) { (c: Character)->Bool in
    if c == "," {
        lastWasComma = !lastWasComma
    }
    else {
        lastWasComma = false
    }
    return lastWasComma
}.map(String.init)

debugPrint(array)
// prints ["a", "b", "c", ",", "1", "2", "3"]
```

(this is for 2.0 - if you’re on 1.2, drop the `.characters` and the `map` from the end, since strings are directly sliceable before 2.0)

Comment: This is clever, I like clever. Wonder how performance is compared to `componentsSeparatedByString`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my last comment, there is a problem on strings such as `"a,,,,b"`? How can you know if the result is: `["a", ",", "", "b"]` or `["a", "", ",", "b"]`?

Comment: The `split` will probably be more efficient. It creates subslices  of the original string, referencing the original memory, whereas `componentsSeparatedByString` creates a string object for each component. The only risk is memory leakage if you leave just one of those subslices alive, they cause the entire string to remain in memory.

Comment: @Zaphod since that’s fundamentally ambiguous, I think you have to make an assumption such as “empty strings aren’t allowed” or “only single characters”. Otherwise, you'd have to have an escaping mechanism rather than a simple “three in a row” rule.

Comment: This also works: `lastWasComma = c == "," && !lastWasComma; return lastWasComma`